# Power Automate Desktop でoutlookからメールメッセージを取得したがメールの送信元アドレスがつかめません

Tags: windows

Power Automate Desktopでメールを扱うために「outlookからメールメッセージを取得」のアクションを実行しました。

RetreivedEmailsは取得できているので、確認のため、例として件名を
RetreivedEmails[0].subjectで
例えば「メッセージを表示」のアクションで表示することはできています。

しかしsubjectをfromと置き換えて入力しようとすると構文エラーとなります。

フロー変数欄で変数の詳細表示をしてみるとプロパティ .From に送信元アドレスは表示されています。

送信元アドレスを取得して添付ファイルの保存時のフォルダ名にしたく考えております。

送信元アドレスをうまく取得できる方法をご存知の方、ご指導方よろしくお願いします。

Comment: すみません少し付記します。添付ファイルを保存する際にフォルダを生成したく考えており、そのフォルダ名に送信元アドレスを編集したいので、送信元アドレスを取得したい状況にあります。

Comment: 質問は後からでも編集できるので、コメント欄ではなく必要に応じて直接本文に追記してください。また、できれば (質問本文で) 句読点も正しく使って欲しいです。

Comment: すみません落ち着いて再度入力します

Comment: こんな記事があります。[Power Automate: メールアドレスの表示名を取得する方法](https://qiita.com/baku2san/items/7e8f0b5a47b4fe3451fc) 他にこんな記事やQ&Aがあり単純には取得出来なさそうです。[【Power Automate Desktop】Outlook内の受信メール一覧を取得する](https://powervbadesktop.com/outlook6/), [Retrieve email messages in PAD - logic of "From contains" field](https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Power-Automate-Desktop/Retrieve-email-messages-in-PAD-logic-of-quot-From-contains-quot/td-p/855036), [How to get the sender name from Outlook 365 in PAD?](https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Power-Automate-Desktop/How-to-get-the-sender-name-from-Outlook-365-in-PAD/td-p/1484924)

Comment: 一筋縄では行かないことわかりました。早速の回答ありがとうございました。